# SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value. Windows Phone Local Database

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using the local database example taht Microsoft created.

I can add items to the list, and delete them. But I now want to select the items and get the text of the item and use that in the next page.

This is the select changed event:

```
 private void allToDoItemsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LiveTimes.xaml?selectedItem=" + allToDoItemsListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

    //    string urlWIthData = string.Format("/LiveTimes.xaml?name={0}", " ");
    //    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlWIthData, UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Then this is the on page load on the other page.

```
 string selectedIndex = "";
       if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
       {
           int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
           DataContext = App.ViewModel.HomeToDoItems[index];

       }
```

Then when i use this, the error is on the DataContext line.

Whats the solution?

Comment: what is the error that you're getting on the DataContext Line? and do you have a static in your App class for the ViewModel?

Comment: The error is SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value. Not sure what you mean by the static in viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in the above code that you have shown, The actual problem may be in the way how you defined your ViewModel and HomeToDoItems . It helps us to solve your problem, if you can show some of that code.

Also before setting your data to DataContext, try the following steps:
First, make sure you are getting the valid selectedIndex.

```
var tempData = App.ViewModel.HomeToDoItems[index];
DataContext = tempData;
```

And then insert a break point at tempData to check whether you are getting the expected data.

This answer may not solve your problem, but guide you in identifying the actual problem.